# autocompletemode search results are very slow

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Is there a way to improve the speed of autocompletemode suggestions in vb.net?

The functionality of autocomplete command works fine on small custom source lists. But when the custom source items reach 100 000, it is slow but works definitely.

My code :

```
Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To Dtset.Tables("Example").Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(Dtset.Tables("Example").Rows(i)(cmboxfnd1.Text).ToString())

    Next
    cmbox1txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    cmbox1txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    cmbox1txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
```

Please do help.

Comment: you need to query database each time. it will be faster to get top 20 starting with "whatever typed"

Comment: I just tested this on ***10,000 +*** records and it work's fine. Is there something you are leaving out? Also another option you can try is: `AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems` and then set the `DataSource` to `Dtset.Tables("Example")`. This will set the source to the `ComboBox` and then use these items for the suggest... Both way's worked great for me.

Comment: Claudius:- Querying was certainly going to be my last resort to many fields that I have. But was wondering if there is an alternative for it.
Codexer:- I have the same code as you suggested for querying the various columns I have in my database. But I needed autocomplete suggestion for the corresponding values of that column.

Comment: Codexer~
Pardon me, I couldn't interpret your solution before but now I have tried this code and still it does take time.
`Private Sub cmboxfnd3_MouseClick(e,e) Handles cmboxfnd3.MouseClick
cmboxfnd3.Items.Clear()
For i = 0 To Dtset.Tables("Example").Rows.Count - 1
            cmboxfnd3.Items.Add(Dtset.Tables("Example").Rows(i).Item(cmboxfnd1.Text).ToString())
Next
End Sub
Private Sub cmboxfnd3_TextChanged(e,e) Handles cmboxfnd3.TextChanged
      cmboxfnd3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        cmboxfnd3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    End Sub`